# Python ElementTree : write to the file it is parsing already

Tags: python, xml, elementtree

I am currently writing my XML to another file in the following manner

```
filepath = folderName + "/config.xml"
config = ET.parse(filepath)
...
config.write(open(folderName + "/config.xml", 'w+b'))
```

My question is how can I write to the same file that is currently open by ET ?

Comment: After `config = ET.parse(filepath)` elementtree is done with the file. Its not open and you can write to it without harm.

Comment: yes that seems to fix the problem seems like I was having write issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can provide the path to the same file you've used to read the XML data from:

```
config.write(filepath)
```